# Simple Pivot in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets-api, looker-studio

I am trying to re-create a simple pivot from Google spreadsheet to Google Data Studio.

Google spreadsheet table.

[image]

Pivot in Google Spreadsheet as row is 'Date' , Column is 'Name' and the **Values** is simply a Calculated field, the 'Address'.
[image]

OutPut below

[image]

*Problem:* Is this possible in Google data studio some how? 
I cannot find any articles about Value Fields in Google Data studio.
Lastly, the blank cells returns the value of 'null' in Data Studio, is there any way to clear the data?

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the "null" data. To fix this Select the table -> Go to style -> Missing Data -> Select Show "" (Blank)

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio pivot tables only support metrics that can be aggregated (numeric values). You cannot do a string aggregation(concat) so your use case is not currently supported.